# Spring security proxy issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, proxy

I have a general question. I have a web project written using Spring Security 3.2 and Spring 4. I deployed project in Tomcat 7.0. There are 2 roles in spring sec for project users: USER and COMPANY. When I log in from home computer (without any proxy), everything works fine. But if I login from my work computer (my computer is behind company proxy) my web application does not work properly, It cannot get localization or often it gives USER role to company account and etc. I looked for this issue in web, but cannot find any solutions. Hope anybody can figure out what can be the reason. Thanks in advance..

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="securityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="securityExpressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/login" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/account/register" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/main" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/profile" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/wishlist" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/messagebox" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/settings" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/search" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY')"/>



    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" />

    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"/>
    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    p:sessionAuthenticationStrategy-ref="sas"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager"
      p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
      p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
     p:defaultFailureUrl="/login?fail=true" />

  <!-- We just actually need to set the default target url here -->
<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
     p:defaultTargetUrl="/main" />

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
     p:loginFormUrl="/login"/>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="service.CustomAuthenticationManager">
</bean>


<!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>


<bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="filter.AzunisConcurrentSessionFilter"
          p:sessionRegistry-ref="sessionRegistry"
          p:expiredUrl="/login" /> 
<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy"
         p:maximumSessions="-1" p:exceptionIfMaximumExceeded="false" p:alwaysCreateSession="true">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
</bean>

<!-- Maintains a registry of SessionInformation instances
       See: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html -->
<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

Comment: Please share your spring security configuration. This will help to provide better answer.

Comment: sorry. updated the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the caching mechanism of the proxy. Let the login and landingpage site expiring with in your Response Header.